# Changing grid position in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I'm trying to make a table to represent the relationship between categorical values based on their count. This is my current code:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=brewer['YlGnBu'][4], low=df['count'].min(), high=df['count'].max())
tooltips = [
    ("Resource", "@org:resoure"),
    ("Activity", "@concept:name"),
    ("Count", "@count"),
]
p = figure(plot_width=df['org:resource'].nunique()*180, plot_height=df['concept:name'].nunique()*100, title="US Unemployment 1948—2016",
           y_range=df['concept:name'].unique(), x_range=df['org:resource'].unique(),x_axis_location="above", tooltips=tooltips)

p.rect(y="concept:name", x="org:resource", width=1, height=1, source=source,
       line_color=None, fill_color=transform('count', mapper))

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, location=(0, 0),
                     ticker=BasicTicker(),
                     formatter=PrintfTickFormatter(format="%d%%"))

p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

p.axis.axis_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "13px"
p.axis.major_label_standoff = 0
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 0

output_notebook()
show(p)
```

However, this code produces a grid that does not suite categorical values. How can I shift the grid down?

[current visual produced by code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrMRm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `FixedTicker`.

Here is a very basic example where `p.rect()` is used.

| **old** | **new** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: original ticker] | [image: shiftet ticker] |

The code is very similar, except the ticks are shifted by `0.5` on both axis in the new version using the `FixedTicker` I mentioned.

**old**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

data = [1, 5]
plot = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
plot.rect(x=data, y=data, width=1, height=1, color="#CAB2D6")

show(plot)
```

**new**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import FixedTicker

data = [1, 5]
plot = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
plot.rect(x=data, y=data, width=1, height=1, color="#CAB2D6")

_max = max(data)
plot.xaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=[x+0.5 for x in range(_max+1)])
plot.yaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=[x+0.5 for x in range(_max+1)])

show(plot)
```